# How can I install the Network Security Toolkit (NST) in Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, security

How can I install [NST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Security_Toolkit) in Ubuntu?  I have searched but found nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Network Security Toolkit](http://networksecuritytoolkit.org/nst/index.html) is a Linux-based Live CD distribution(similar to Fedora/RedHat) and is not meant to be installed as discrete Ubuntu package.

There are numerous packages used in NST(i.e wireshark, ntop, and nmap) that can also be installed independently of the NST Live CD. But, you will need to find them separately and install them one-by-one through either Synaptic, the command line, or the Ubuntu Software center.

See the list of packages offered by NST [here](http://www.networksecuritytoolkit.org/nst/links.html). Many of the tools included in this distribution are listed in Sectools.org's [Top 125 Network Security Tools](http://sectools.org/) list.

The NST ISO can be downloaded from [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nst/files/).

For an overview of the NST package, see [NST General Information](http://wiki.networksecuritytoolkit.org/nstwiki/index.php/NST_General_Information).